# Saving cropped file

Tags: php

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$src1 = $row['file_name'];
$targ_w = $targ_h = 350;
$jpeg_quality = 90;
$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src1);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

header('Content-type: image/jpg');
imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);
```

How to go about saving file for this example? 
this is the source file name, $src1 = $row['file_name'];
I can only preview the file, but not save it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second parameter of [imagejpeg](http://php.net/imagejpeg) is save path.

```
imagejpeg($dst_r, $src1,$jpeg_quality);
```

Comment: @minitech
But the $src1 is the initial file name, what i want a different file name for the cropped file. and how should i include the destination for the file ?

Comment: @apple: you can select whatever path you like. If you keep $src1 there, old image will be replaced with the cropped one

Comment: How should i select the path ? is it $dst_r? when i change the code from imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality); to imagejpeg($dst_r, $src1,$jpeg_quality); 
 it says error ..

Comment: So actually i have to add imagejpeg($dst_r, $src1,$jpeg_quality); <-- this, and instead of replacing it with imagejpeg($dst_r, null,$jpeg_quality); and it will be added to the destination folder . thanks!

Comment: @apple: Sorry for not responding, if you need to mention me you have to do it on *my* answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass a filename to [`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/imagejpeg):

```
imagejpeg($dst_r, $src1, $jpeg_quality);
```